# Подписаться на изменение свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, уведомления, property

У меня есть созданный UserControl. Несколько его экземпляров я добавляю на MainWindow. Передо мной стоит задача: все экземпляры этого UserControl уведомить об изменении свойства в одном из этих UserControl'ов.

Если быть точнее, то на UserControl есть TextBlock, при нажатии на него, Foregraund становится белым, а все остальные TextBlock'и на всех остальных UserControl'ах должны стать серыми.

Не знаю как реализовать.
Буду благодарен любой помощи.

P.S.

```
        private SolidColorBrush selectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        private SolidColorBrush notSelectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,144, 161, 169));

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                if(IsSelected)
                      //Уведомить
                txb.Foreground = IsSelected ? selectedColor : notSelectedColor;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public SettingsTreeViewTitle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void SettingsTreeViewTitle_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Раз взялись за WPF, то лучше использовать MVVM 2) Если все таки хотите себе ноги отстрелить вашим текущим подходом, то можете подписать само окно на собфтие контрола, и пусть контрол при изменении оповещает окно, а окно потом делает все, что хочет, с контролами.

Comment: В качестве сумасшедшей идеи: поместить все контролы в RadioButton и привязаться к его свойству IsChecked